# Network storage with authentication for Windows and Linux containers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smb

I am looking to build multiple file providers into an ASP.net core 3.1 or above Web API but want to try and cover as many bases through the same implementation. My ASP.net application requires to be hosted on either Linux or Windows.

The structure is based on ASP.net boilerplate.

I am currently using basic file provider for the local system for storing large files, but now looking to create one for SMB NAS with username and password.
My main issue lies with utilizing a network share in the solution that will work on both Windows OS and Linux.

I did look at the following which will work fine for a console application but not a web application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri(@"\\servername"), "Basic", credential);

    try
    {
        var t = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\servername\main");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Another way that I have used in the past for dedicate Windows deployment is by mapping a drive with credentials either by PInvoke or using net use as a new process. This would be fine for a Windows box but I expect this to fail on a Linux build / container.

I am not to sure what the best way to utilise a SMB share with authentication for both Windows and Linux deployments in ASP.net core. Majority of Microsoft documentation regarding storage tends to point to Azure storage.

Another option might be to use BLOB storage, whether this is local, network attached or cloud based. I have looked into the volo abp template which seems to be very similar to aspnet boilerplate structure. The easiest and simplest solution would be to utilise one of these modules but when its injected the modules are not compatible.

For ref [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing-File-System)

Thanks